# Adding/Removing Markers on android google map every 30 seconds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, executorservice

I'm trying to add/remove markers to my GoogleMap every 30 seconds with ScheduledExecutorService.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mapObjects();
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

My mapObjects()

```
private void mapObjects() {
    mMap.clear();
    mapThings();
}
```

My mapThings()

```
private void mapThings() {
    for (MarkerOptions markerOptions : mappedThings.values()) {
        mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
}
```

My mapObjects() method works, because I  run it outside of the executor service in onMapReady, which works fine.
However in the timer, it doesn't work.

Comment: please write down your exact issue

Comment: it doesnt work - it's running on the UI thread.